# Overriding Parent's Element Click Event from Child Element

Tags: jquery

I have following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div>test</div></td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using JQuery, I have some code that runs when user click on TR element. It works well.

However, when someone click the DIV inside the TD element, I want only the "click" event of the DIV and not the parent's TR "click" event.

How can I do that?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use stopPropagation:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').bind('click', function (e) {
        console.log('tr');
    });
    $('div').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
       console.log('div');
   });
```

});

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hr3JJ/3/)

Answer (score 3):

event.stopImmediatePropagation() worked for me :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I could not add comment on any above answers as those are not my answers. evt.stopPropagation() did not worked for me, whereas event.stopImmediatePropagation() did, thats why I feel it worthy to share this with others :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at jQuery's event.stopPropagation()

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 1):

Use `evt.stopPropagation` in your `click` handler.

Comment: `preventDefault()` doesn't stop event bubbling.